# How to get enum value, string, and description

Tags: vb.net, enums

I am trying to loop through my enum and extract the value, string, and description out of it? How can I do this?

```
Enum Fruits
        <Description("$1.99/lb")> Apple = 1
        <Description("$0.99/lb")> Banana= 2
        <Description("$3.99/lb")> Orange= 3
End Enum
```

Persudo code

```
For Each item in Fruits
   Dim value as integer
   Dim text as string 
   Dim description as string
   Dim returnText = String.Format("ID: {0}  {1} is {2}", value, text, description) 
Next
```

I will like to get:

ID: 1 Apple is $1.99/lb

ID: 2 Banana is $0.99/lb

ID: 3 Orange is $3.99/lb

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a really bad way to manage data elements: every time the price of bananas goes up you have to change the code.  Descriptions should be reserved for static items.  Ex:

```
Friend Enum ImgSizes
     <Description("Large,  1600x900")> Lg = 1600               
     <Description("Medium, 1280x720")> Med = 1280
     <Description("Small,   720x480")> Sm = 720
End Enum
```

Here, the Description might be fetched for display in a combobox to provide a friendly translation. Otherwise, the `value` is just the integer value of the enum, and the name can be gotten from `.ToString`.  The only trick is the description:

```
Shared Function GetDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
   Dim fi As FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
   Dim attr() As DescriptionAttribute = DirectCast(
       fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), 
          DescriptionAttribute())
   If attr.Length > 0 Then
       Return attr(0).Description
   Else
       Return EnumConstant.ToString()
   End If
End Function
```

Your loop needs work and you need to use OPTION STRICT.  Loop thru the values to get the info you want.  The index variable must `As Fruits` otehrwise it is not a Enum/Friuts, but an integer or object and nothing will work.

```
For Each v As Fruit In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Fruits))
    returnText = String.Format("ID: {0}  {1} is {2}", 
          Convert.ToInt32(v), v.ToString, 
          GetDescription(GetType(v)) 
Next
```

Comment: 1. v.value threw me an error saying "value" is not an member.

Comment: You are right, this is a bad way to manage data elements, and fortunately these are only dummy data. : ) Something I came up with in  2 mins. I guess i should have given more thought on this.

Comment: my mistake copying too much of your code.  it should be just `Convert.ToInt32(v)`  PLUS oranges are way too expensive ;)